# Como fazer um upload e um download na mesma requisição usando AngularJS e Web api?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma funcionalidade que receberá uma planilha em formato .xlsx, realizará um processamento e devolverá essa planilha com as colunas adicionadas, nesse caso eu deveria realizar um upload de um arquivo e no success faria o download. Nas minhas tentativas ou eu consigo enviar o arquivo ou apenas receber ainda não consegui os dois sem corromper o arquivo de retorno, no código a seguir eu consigo receber o arquivo, realizar o processamento e realizar o download porém o arquivo vem corrompido, não acredito que seja problema na minha api pois se eu fizer uma chamada get ou até post eu consigo realizar o download do arquivo.

### Angular

```
 // chamada do upload.
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {

    //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
    var data = new FormData();

    for (var i in $scope.files) {
        data.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i]);
    }

    // ADD LISTENERS.
    var objXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    objXhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    //objXhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    objXhr.onload = onsuccess;
    objXhr.onerror = onerror;

    // SEND FILE DETAILS TO THE API.
    objXhr.open("POST", "/api/v1/public/PostContent");
    objXhr.send(data);

    function onsuccess(result) {
        if (result == null) {
            toastr["error"]("RETORNO NULO", "Título da mensagem");
        }
        var blob = new Blob([result], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
    };

    function onerror(result) {

        if (result.status == 415) {
            toastr["error"]("Arquivo não suportado", "Título da mensagem");
        } else {
            toastr["error"]("Erro ao tentar ler o arquivo", "Título da mensagem");
        }
    };
}
```

### Controller Web Api

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("PostContent")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostContent()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        MultipartFileData file = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault();

        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
        var package = new ExcelPackage(info)
        //PROCESSAMENTO DA PLANILHA

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            package.SaveAs(ms);

            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = $"Vai{ DateTime.Now }.xlsx"
            };
            return result;
}
```

### Na View Carregando o arquivo

```
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFileDetails(this)" />

        <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFiles()">Carregar</button>
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue como ficou o código, estou usando [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) por isso a diretiva 'apsUploadFile' para deixar o botão do input file no estilo do material design.

### Angular

```
    app.controller('processoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

        function send(data, uploadUrl, success, error) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                for (var key in data) {
                    fd.append(key, data[key]);
                }
                return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
                });
            };

        $scope.uploadArquivo = function (data) {
                var upload = { data: data };
                var uploadUrl = 'api/enviaraquivo';
                var nomearquivo = $('input').val().split('\\')[2].split('.')[0];
                send(upload, uploadUrl).
                    then(function (result, status, xhr) {
                        $scope.actived = !$scope.actived;
                        $scope.publicacaonaoencontrada = false;
                        $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);
                        var filename = nomearquivo + '_Analisada_.xlsx';
                        var blob = new Blob([result.data], { type:     "application/octet-stream" });
                        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                            // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                        } else {
                            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                            if (filename) {
                                // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                                var a = document.createElement("a");
                                // safari doesn't support this yet
                                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                                    window.location = downloadUrl;
                                } else {
                                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                                    a.download = filename;
                                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                                    a.click();
                                }
                            } else {
                                window.location = downloadUrl;
                            }

                            setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100);
                        }
                       alert('arquivo processado com sucesso');
                    }, function (result) {
                        $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);

                        if (result.status == 401) {
                            alert('acesso não autorizado, realize o login');
                        } else {
                            alert('Arquivo fora dos padrões');
                        }

                    });
            }
    }).directive('apsUploadFile', apsUploadFile);
//Código para colocar um design material no input file

function apsUploadFile() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input id="upload"  accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" type="file" class="ng-hide" file-model="upload">' +
            ' <md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary" aria-label="attach_file"> Carregar planilha </md-button>' +
            '<md-input-container class="input-file-text" md-no-float><input id="textInput" ng-model="fileName" type="text" placeholder="Nenhum arquivo selecionado" ng-readonly="true"></md-input-container>' +
            '<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-disabled="upload == null" ng-click="uploadArquivo(upload)">Upload</md-button>',
        link: apsUploadFileLink
    };
    return directive;
}

function apsUploadFileLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    var input = $(element[0].querySelector('#upload'));
    var button = $(element[0].querySelector('#uploadButton'));
    var textInput = $(element[0].querySelector('#textInput'));

    if (input.length && button.length && textInput.length) {
        button.click(function (e) {
            input.click();
        });
        textInput.click(function (e) {
            input.click();
        });
    }

    input.on('change', function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files[0]) {
            scope.fileName = files[0].name;
        } else {
            scope.fileName = null;
        }
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

### View

```
<div ng-controller="processoCtrl as processo">
    <div class="upload-page">
        <div class="form">
            <form method="post" target="hidden-form">
                <h2>Carregue o arquivo</h2>
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <md-content layout-padding layout="row" layout-align="start end">
                            <aps-upload-file style="text-align: center;"></aps-upload-file>
                        </md-content>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controler Web Api

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("enviararquivo")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostArquivo()
    {

        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);

        try
        {
            CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"));
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            MultipartFileData file = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault();

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
            var planilhaDaRequisicao = new ExcelPackage(info);
            MemoryStream streamPlanilhaRequisicao = new MemoryStream();
            planilhaDaRequisicao.SaveAs(streamPlanilhaRequisicao);

            var streamPlanilhaAnalizada = servicePublicacao.VerificaPublicacao(streamPlanilhaRequisicao);
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(streamPlanilhaAnalizada.GetBuffer())
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = $"download{ DateTime.Now }.xlsx"
            };

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Arquivo fora dos padrões para consulta");
        }
    }
```

Para processamento da planilha estou usando a biblioteca [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/).